ServiceBase.onSessionChange not catching events
I am trying to catch the session change events using .Net framework 4.7. According to Documentation , I have to override the OnSessionChange() method and change the CanHandleSessionChangeEvent to true but still I am unable to catch any event.
Here is the code:
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
    this.ServiceName = "WindowsService1";
}

protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
{

    // Handle session change event
    switch (changeDescription.Reason)
    {
        case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogon:
            // Code to execute when a user logs on
            break;
        case SessionChangeReason.SessionLogoff:
            // Code to execute when a user logs off
            break;
        case SessionChangeReason.SessionLock:
            // Code to execute when a session is locked
            break;
        case SessionChangeReason.SessionUnlock:
            // Code to execute when a session is unlocked
            break;
        // Handle other session change reasons if needed
        default:
            break;
    }
}

Same question has been asked on the stack overflow, but there is no solution to this. Is there any issue with my code?
Can anybody please help!
I expect to catch the on session change when the computer is locked or unlocked!
